Example of an R object that is not deparse-able
base::deparse() documentation page says:

Using control = "all" comes closest to making deparse() an inverse of parse(). However, not all objects are deparse-able even with this option and a warning will be issued if the function recognizes that it is being asked to do the impossible.

Please provide an example of an object that is not deparse-able?

This could be an interesting question but it would help to specify what you mean by deparse-able. For example, do environments count? deparse(.GlobalEnv) returns "<environment>", which is sort of descriptive, but it doesn't tell you how to reconstruct the original object.

This is the full sentence from the documentation linked: "However, not all objects are deparse-able even with this option and a warning will be issued if the function recognizes that it is being asked to do the impossible." In light of this sentence, I would consider it not deparse-able if a warning is issued.

In that case, deparse(.GlobalEnv, control = "all") does raise a warning, and so meets the definition of not being deparse-able (the warning only appears with control="all"). So I suppose that's what the documentation page is referring to, and all non-deparseable objects will still return some printed representation that cannot reconstruct the object

Classes can get weird too I think. If you try the example from the S7 vignette (https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/S7/vignettes/S7.html) I get an error if I run deparse(lola) (tested with R 4.3.3)

Interesting ... btw I get the same error on R 4.2.1

It appears that S7 objects are not deparsable. Borrowing the example from the vignette
library(S7)
dog <- new_class("dog", properties = list(
  name = class_character,
  age = class_numeric
))
lola <- dog(name = "Lola", age = 11)
deparse(lola)
# Error in deparse(lola) : 'S4SXP': should not happen - please report

My guess is that such an object should be deparsable so maybe future updates may change that. Interesting deparse(dog) seems to work fine.

This it is certainly not deparse-able, so I will accept it (although it conceivably could be deparse-able). However, I think the documentation was driving at "being asked to do the impossible", i.e. trying to deparse an object for which there is no practical literal syntax, and so it just returns some default representation and gives a warning. As @SamR commented, deparse(.GlobalEnv, control = "all") is an example of this
